# Angular 5 firebase upload file title error

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have my upload service which is uploading files to storages, get's file name and url then writes it in db and firestore :

```
project:AngularFirestoreCollection<Project[]>
pushUpload(upload: Project) {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${upload.file.name}`).put(upload.file);

    uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
      (snapshot: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot) =>  {
        // upload in progress
        const snap = snapshot;
        upload.progress = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100

      },
      (error) => {
        // upload failed
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        // upload success
        if (uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL) {
          upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
          upload.name = upload.file.name;
          this.fire.collection(`users/${this.auth.userId}/projects`).add( { photoURL: upload.url, file: upload.file.name, title: upload.title })
          this.saveFileData(upload);
          return;
        } else {
          console.error('No download URL!');
        }


      },

    );
  }
```

**Project.ts :**

```
export class Project {
  $key: string;
  file: File;
  name: string;
  title:string;
  url: string;
  progress: number;
  createdAt: Date = new Date();

  constructor(file: File) {
    this.file = file;
  }
}
```

As you see I have title in my project.ts and I am trying to write it like this :

In service :

```
 this.fire.collection(`users/${this.auth.userId}/projects`).add( { photoURL: upload.url, file: upload.file.name, title: upload.title })
```

**In component :**

```
export class AddProjectComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedFiles: FileList | null;
  currentUpload: Project;
  project = {} as Project;
  constructor(public navSrv: NavService,) { }

  detectFiles($event: Event) {
    this.selectedFiles = ($event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;
  }
  uploadSingle() {
    const file = this.selectedFiles;
    if (file && file.length === 1) {
      this.currentUpload = new Project(file.item(0));
      this.navSrv.pushUpload(this.currentUpload);
    } else {
      console.error('No file found!');
    }
  }

  uploadMulti() {
    const files = this.selectedFiles;
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      console.error('No Multi Files found!');
      return;
    }

    Array.from(files).forEach((file) => {
      this.currentUpload = new Project(file);
      this.navSrv.pushUpload(this.currentUpload);
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**In html  :**

```
<input type="text" ([ngModel])="project.title">
```

**Error :**

> core.js:1350 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError:
>   [code=invalid-argument]: Function DocumentReference.set() called with
>   invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field
>   title) FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with
>   invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field
>   title)

**My question is: Why I can write name, url but can't write title ?**

Comment: `title:string;` hit space in between `:` and `string`

Comment: Same error, saw that before and fixed.

Comment: Did you check the value op upload.title before you try to write it to firestore? The error you are getting is pretty clear: title is undefined.

Comment: How can I check the title if its a string ?

Comment: console.log("check : ", this.project.title) ---- Console.log : check :  undefined (but it should be undefined if it has no value before the input, no ?